# Db2 10.1 is not creating database in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, db2

I have installed db2 10.1 on windows 8 but each time i am creating database it is generating

error:

**SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does     not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation**

but i have confirmed that user name by whom db2 is installed have proper administrative authority.

Note: I noticed one thing that in previous installation the user that installed automatically become the member of DB2ADMNS group but in my case there was no any group of name DB2ADMNS exist. for time being i have created a new group of DB2ADMNS but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ID with which you execute the `CREATE DATABASE` command must be a member of the Administrators group on the local machine.

If your machine is part of a domain, and the ID you are using is a domain ID, then you will need to either:

1. Use the ID the DB2 service is running under (default is `db2admin`)
2. Set the DB2 Registry Variable `DB2_GRP_LOOKUP` to `LOCAL` to force DB2 to perform group enumeration on the local machine (even for domain accounts).  You can do this by executing the following command from a DB2 Command Window:

   `db2set DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=LOCAL`

   And then restarting the DB2 instance.

Comment: @lan its so nice to answer in such a manner, yes these could be the prime reason, but it was not my case.

Comment: i think this question covers all possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following problem and fixed it:

I was using domain user name but i have not set the DNS Server address as gateway so Db2 was treating it as default local user and that have not administrative authority.